# jQuery: how to delete list items from lists?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a way with jQuery to remove all the LIs inside a UL with an id of 'myList'?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The following will do the trick:

```
$('#myList li').remove();
```

But you should familiarize yourself with [jQuery's supported selectors](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors) and [manipulation](http://docs.jquery.com/Manipulation)

Answer (score 6):

Slightly simpler approach:

```
$("#myList").empty();
```

See [`empty()`](http://docs.jquery.com/Manipulation/empty). The other answer works fine for this but gets more awkward for other elements that can have different child elements (eg tables).

Comment: +1 for I think an answer that would actually run faster vs. finding 'li' children (and the accepted query would find nested li's as well) then removing them.